# moving a contact to the bottom of the list

Tags: contacts, google-account

I have a Galaxy Note 2 with CM 10.2 and gapps installed. I keep my contacts in Google and synchronize them to the phone. This works fine.

I would like to move selected contacts to the bottom of the list (usually service contacts which I want to have handy but "on the side")

In other words in my list of contacts I would like to move from

```
Adam Green
Bank
Claire Jones
```

to

```
Adam Green
Claire Jones
Bank
```

I tried to prefix Bank (in the example above) with various symbols (`_`, `~`, `|`) but even though they are before or after normal lettres in ASCII, such entries always end up (grouped) at the **top** of the list.

Any idea how to move them to the bottom? (short of prefixing them with `ZZZ`)

Answer (score 0):

I think special characters and numbers are grouped together, and would appear at the top when sorted alphabetically.

The way I'd order `special contacts` is just like what you suggested, prefixing them with `z` so they'd move to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

With another phone, I also used to move some contacts (like administrative contacts) off the way (that's at the end of the list) by adding a special character prefix to their name. So apparently this is not possible with Android and Google Contacts app.

I am not completely happy with adding a "zz" prefix... but there is another way: by selecting the contact groups that you want to see in the list (Android 4.4.2)

1. put the contacts that you want "on the side" in a group, for example "admin"
2. in the app menu (of the individual contacts view), choose "Contacts to display"
3. choose "Customise (o)"
4. uncheck the groups that you do not want to see, and check "All other contacts"

Now you have just your desired contacts in the main contact list. To access the other ones (like administrative contacts), open their group.